# How to print a new line in lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, newline

I have tried a lot to print a new line in lisp. I want to print a new line like java (system.out.println()), and not necessarily having anything. I know that print goes to a new line however I must have a variable inside it. Is there a function in lisp that does not need a variable and goes to a new line?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the [`TERPRI`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_terpri.htm#fresh-line) function (the name stands for "terminate printing", as it's intended to be used to terminate a line of output).

```
(terpri)
```

You could also use `FRESH-LINE`. This prints a newline unless you're already at the start of a line.